# Install lib32v4l-0 but receiving dependency error

Tags: package-management, deb

I am trying to install `lib32v4l-0_0.6.4-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb` but I get the following error:

```
 (Reading database ... 406870 files and directories currently installed.)
 Preparing to unpack lib32v4l-0_0.6.4-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
 Unpacking lib32v4l-0 (0.6.4-1ubuntu1) over (0.6.4-1ubuntu1) ...
 dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of lib32v4l-0:
  lib32v4l-0 depends on libv4l-0 (= 0.6.4-1ubuntu1); however:
   Version of libv4l-0:amd64 on system is 1.0.1-1.

 dpkg: error processing package lib32v4l-0 (--install):
  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
 Errors were encountered while processing:
  lib32v4l-0
```

Then I run `sudo apt-get upgrade` which gives me:

```
 Reading package lists... Done
 Building dependency tree       
 Reading state information... Done
 You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
 The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  lib32v4l-0 : Depends: libv4l-0 (= 0.6.4-1ubuntu1) but 1.0.1-1 is installed
 E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

Then I run `sudo apt-get upgrade -f`:

```
 Reading package lists... Done
 Building dependency tree       
 Reading state information... Done
 Correcting dependencies... Done
 Calculating upgrade... Done
 The following packages will be REMOVED:
   lib32v4l-0
 The following packages have been kept back:
   hostapd
 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
 1 not fully installed or removed.
 After this operation, 287 kB disk space will be freed.
 Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
 (Reading database ... 406869 files and directories currently installed.)
 Removing lib32v4l-0 (0.6.4-1ubuntu1) ...
 Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6) ...
```

I'm trying to install the `lib32v4l-0_0.6.4-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb` package because I need to install the `ia32-libs_2.7ubuntu26.1_amd64.deb` package which depends on it.
Does anyone know a solution (or even better way)?

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04LTS

Comment: I am afraid you got it backwards. `ia32-libs` [provides](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/lib32v4l-0) `lib32v4l`, not depends on it.